# Русские символы в условии WHERE mysqli запроса

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, на некоторых ячейках не проходит запрос к базе данных, вызываемый таким образом:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "UPDATE `table` SET `data` = ? WHERE `table`.`data` = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newcontent, $originalcontent);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

К примеру, если содержимое ячейки data:

```
<img src="http://dd.com/1.jpg">
```

- то все проходит нормально.

А если:

```
г<img src="http://dd.com/1.jpg">
```

- то значение в ячейке не обновляется. Если в ячейке вместо русской буквы латинская или цифра - все проходит нормально.

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что скорее всего проблема в кодировке.

При подключении к базе данных использую запрос:

```
mysqli_query($dbconnection,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Думал, что он решит все проблемы кодировок (до этого момента решал, все символы отображаются корректно как при выводе, так и при вводе данных в базу - но для условия WHERE, видимо, этого недостаточно).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как средствами php решить эту проблему.

Comment: г<img src="http://dd.com/1.jpg"> эту `г` как видите? В браузере в поле ввода забиваете или на сервере обнаруживаете каким-то образом (в логах например)? Может из браузера приходят не правильная кодировка

Comment: @Sergey Вижу её через `echo $originalcontent;`. Браузер почти никак не участвует у меня, только инициирует запуск сценария. Сценарий обрабатывает данные из базы данных - там где русские буквы - условие не выполняется.

Comment: Т.е. `г` формируется программно? Где-то в тексте программы написано типа такого `$str = "г" + чего-то там`? Кодировка самого текста программы какая? windows 1251, koi8, utf-8?

Comment: @Sergey нет, `г` уже содержится в базе данных, которые программа обрабатывает. Кодировка самого текста программы - utf-8

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset()` Это предпочтительный способ задания набора символов. Использование для этих целей функции `mysqli_query()` (например `SET NAMES utf8`) не рекомендуется. Может как раз Ваш случай

Comment: https://school-php.com/tricks/18/vyistavlyaem-kodirovku-utf-8

Comment: @Sergey Да, такой способ решил проблему. В этом было дело. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользователь Сергей подсказал решение в комментариях. Если кодировку объявлять так:

```
mysqli_set_charset($dbconnection,'utf8');
```

То всё проходит корректно.

Answer (score -1):

1. Попробуйте использовать "SET NAMES utf8" вместо "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'" .
2. Попробуйте формировать запрос полностью, вместо "UPDATE `table` SET `data` = ? WHERE `table`.`data` = ?" напишите прямо "UPDATE `table` SET `data` = '$newcontent' WHERE `data` = '$originalcontent'".

Comment: 1. Попробовал вместо и вместе. Не помогает.     2. Так тоже уже пробовал, безрезультатно.

Comment: А кодировка у базы какая? Какая кодировка у файла, который запрос отправляет?

Comment: У файла - utf8. У таблицы кодировка `latin1_swedish_ci`, но у колонки `data` - `utf8_bin`. Сейчас попробовал поменять и у таблицы и колонки на `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` - не помогло.

Comment: Указание кодировки через функцию `mysqli_set_charset()` решило проблему.